# Datastax enterprise graph schema design and cluster sizing

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise-graph

Please advise on following

1)Based on - https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dse-5-0-3-released-huge-performance-gains-for-graph-analytics
where bench-marking is done with each node having 256 GB disk and 256 GB of RAM. Does this mean that entire data is loaded into memory ?
What are node and cluster sizing recommendations?

2)We have a use-case where vertex properties are dynamic and added at runtime. Number of property keys, its name and value can be anything. Something like vertex "entity"(does not have any properties except default id) has edges to vertex "propertydef" and "propertyvalue". Is graph DB right choice for this use-case?

Thanks
Tilak

Comment: Any suggestions ?